# Select rows with equal values in one column and different values in another column Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe with about 400,000 rows but I want to correct some things in it. So I want to select all the rows that have an equal value to the previous one in one column and a different value that the previous one in another column. In other words, x[i] == x[i+1] AND x[j] != x[j+1]. So what I thought about doing is sorting the values using i and j then shifting the dataframe and grouping by. However I am having problems getting out the dataset

Example dataset:

```
 i         j           year       
"foo"     "jar"          5
"foo"     "jam"          5
"hi"      "hell"         6
"hi"      "hello"        6
"good"    "happy"        8
"bad"     "happy"        8
"happy"   "good"         8
```

Desidered output:

```
 i         j           year       
"foo"     "jar"          5
"foo"     "jam"          5
"hi"      "hell"         6
"hi"      "hello"        6
```

Current Code:

```
shifteddf = df.shift()

df1 = df[df["i"]==shifteddf["i"]]

df2 = df[df["j"]!=shifteddf["j"]]

pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Current output:

```
 i         j           year       
"foo"     "jam"          5
"hi"      "hello"        6
```

So I am missing some rows, and I think I am currently doing a fatal error

Comment: based on the condition x[i] == x[i+1] AND x[j] != x[j+1] the second and the last row in desired output should not be included

Comment: Yeah I figured that was the problem, but I am still thinking about a way to resolve. Do you have anything in mind?

Comment: you get the correct result with your code for the condition

Comment: No I don't look at the desired output table, I want all of them even the last and first ones

Answer (score 0):

This can be done based on identical strings and length of strings.

### Method 1

Based on strings You need eq with shift:

```
match = df.i.eq(df.i.shift())
print(df[match | match.shift(-1)])
```

Output #

```
     i      j           year         
0  foo    jar            5    
1  foo    jam            5    
2   hi   hell            6    
3   hi  hello            6
```

### Method 2

If you want by length then simply calculate length first and then group accordingly

```
df['len'] = df['i'].astype(str).map(len)
match = (df.len.groupby(df.i).diff().eq(0))

print(df[match | match.shift(-1)])
```

which also outputs #

```
     i      j          year  len
0  foo    jar            5    3
1  foo    jam            5    3
2   hi   hell            6    2
3   hi  hello            6    2
```